# How to get the address of 64-bit Linux kernel entry point?

Tags: linux

I'm writing a bootloader for Linux by following [The Linux/x86 Boot Protocol](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/arch/x86/boot.html) and I want to use the `64-bit Boot Protocol`. The documentation said I can jump to the 64-bit entry point at the offset 0x200 but it does not work. When I inspect this offset what I found is a `jmp` to the following code:

```
8c d8           MOV        AX,DS
8e c0           MOV        ES,AX
fc              CLD
8c d2           MOV        DX,SS
39 c2           CMP        EDX,EAX
89 e2           MOV        EDX,ESP
74 16           JZ         LAB_0100028f
```

Which is not the same as a 64-bit entry point I found [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.1/arch/x86/boot/compressed/head_64.S#L336):

```
    /*
     * 64bit entry is 0x200 and it is ABI so immutable!
     * We come here either from startup_32 or directly from a
     * 64bit bootloader.
     * If we come here from a bootloader, kernel(text+data+bss+brk),
     * ramdisk, zero_page, command line could be above 4G.
     * We depend on an identity mapped page table being provided
     * that maps our entire kernel(text+data+bss+brk), zero page
     * and command line.
     */

    cld
    cli

    /* Setup data segments. */
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movl    %eax, %ds
    movl    %eax, %es
    movl    %eax, %ss
    movl    %eax, %fs
    movl    %eax, %gs
```